# CoNLL files in hyperparameter tuning using Optuna

Tags: python, optimization, lstm, hyperparameters, optuna

I've been trying to work out how to optimize the hyperparameters in a Bi-LSTM model for PoS and dependency parsing (https://github.com/datquocnguyen/jPTDP).
The model takes CoNLL-U files as input and I am clueless as to how I can go about using them with Optuna.

The hyperparameters are defined in the model as follows:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import pickle, utils, learner, os, os.path, time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--train", dest="conll_train", help="Path to annotated CONLL train file", metavar="FILE", default="N/A")
    parser.add_option("--dev", dest="conll_dev", help="Path to annotated CONLL dev file", metavar="FILE", default="N/A")
    parser.add_option("--test", dest="conll_test", help="Path to CONLL test file", metavar="FILE", default="N/A")
    parser.add_option("--output", dest="conll_test_output", help="File name for predicted output", metavar="FILE", default="N/A")
    parser.add_option("--prevectors", dest="external_embedding", help="Pre-trained vector embeddings", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("--params", dest="params", help="Parameters file", metavar="FILE", default="model.params")
    parser.add_option("--model", dest="model", help="Load/Save model file", metavar="FILE", default="model")
    parser.add_option("--wembedding", type="int", dest="wembedding_dims", default=100)
    parser.add_option("--cembedding", type="int", dest="cembedding_dims", default=50)
    parser.add_option("--pembedding", type="int", dest="pembedding_dims", default=100)
    parser.add_option("--epochs", type="int", dest="epochs", default=30)
    parser.add_option("--hidden", type="int", dest="hidden_units", default=100)
    #parser.add_option("--lr", type="float", dest="learning_rate", default=None)
    parser.add_option("--outdir", type="string", dest="output", default="results")
    parser.add_option("--activation", type="string", dest="activation", default="tanh")
    parser.add_option("--lstmlayers", type="int", dest="lstm_layers", default=2)
    parser.add_option("--lstmdims", type="int", dest="lstm_dims", default=128)
    parser.add_option("--disableblstm", action="store_false", dest="blstmFlag", default=True)
    parser.add_option("--disablelabels", action="store_false", dest="labelsFlag", default=True)
    parser.add_option("--predict", action="store_true", dest="predictFlag", default=False)
    parser.add_option("--bibi-lstm", action="store_false", dest="bibiFlag", default=True)
    parser.add_option("--disablecostaug", action="store_false", dest="costaugFlag", default=True)
    parser.add_option("--dynet-seed", type="int", dest="seed", default=0)
    parser.add_option("--dynet-mem", type="int", dest="mem", default=0)

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    #print 'Using external embedding:', options.external_embedding

    if options.predictFlag:
        with open(options.params, 'r') as paramsfp:
            words, w2i, c2i, pos, rels, stored_opt = pickle.load(paramsfp)
        stored_opt.external_embedding = None
        print 'Loading pre-trained model'
        parser = learner.jPosDepLearner(words, pos, rels, w2i, c2i, stored_opt)
        parser.Load(options.model)
        
        testoutpath = os.path.join(options.output, options.conll_test_output)
        print 'Predicting POS tags and parsing dependencies'
        #ts = time.time()
        #test_pred = list(parser.Predict(options.conll_test))
        #te = time.time()
        #print 'Finished in', te-ts, 'seconds.'
        #utils.write_conll(testoutpath, test_pred)

        with open(testoutpath, 'w') as fh:
            for sentence in parser.Predict(options.conll_test):
                for entry in sentence[1:]:
                    fh.write(str(entry) + '\n')
                fh.write('\n')

    else:
        print("Training file: " + options.conll_train)
        if options.conll_dev != "N/A":
            print("Development file: " + options.conll_dev)

        highestScore = 0.0
        eId = 0

        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(options.output, options.params)) and \
                os.path.isfile(os.path.join(options.output, os.path.basename(options.model))) :

            print 'Found a previous saved model => Loading this model'
            with open(os.path.join(options.output, options.params), 'r') as paramsfp:
                words, w2i, c2i, pos, rels, stored_opt = pickle.load(paramsfp)
            stored_opt.external_embedding = None
            parser = learner.jPosDepLearner(words, pos, rels, w2i, c2i, stored_opt)
            parser.Load(os.path.join(options.output, os.path.basename(options.model)))
            parser.trainer.restart()
            if options.conll_dev != "N/A":
                devPredSents = parser.Predict(options.conll_dev)

                count = 0
                lasCount = 0
                uasCount = 0
                posCount = 0
                poslasCount = 0
                for idSent, devSent in enumerate(devPredSents):
                    conll_devSent = [entry for entry in devSent if isinstance(entry, utils.ConllEntry)]

                    for entry in conll_devSent:
                        if entry.id <= 0:
                            continue
                        if entry.pos == entry.pred_pos and entry.parent_id == entry.pred_parent_id and entry.pred_relation == entry.relation:
                            poslasCount += 1
                        if entry.pos == entry.pred_pos:
                            posCount += 1
                        if entry.parent_id == entry.pred_parent_id and entry.pred_relation == entry.relation:
                            lasCount += 1
                        if entry.parent_id == entry.pred_parent_id:
                            uasCount += 1
                        count += 1

                print "---\nLAS accuracy:\t%.2f" % (float(lasCount) * 100 / count)
                print "UAS accuracy:\t%.2f" % (float(uasCount) * 100 / count)
                print "POS accuracy:\t%.2f" % (float(posCount) * 100 / count)
                print "POS&LAS:\t%.2f" % (float(poslasCount) * 100 / count)

                score = float(poslasCount) * 100 / count
                if score >= highestScore:
                    parser.Save(os.path.join(options.output, os.path.basename(options.model)))
                    highestScore = score

                print "POS&LAS of the previous saved model: %.2f" % (highestScore)

        else:
            print 'Extracting vocabulary'
            words, w2i, c2i, pos, rels = utils.vocab(options.conll_train)

            with open(os.path.join(options.output, options.params), 'w') as paramsfp:
                pickle.dump((words, w2i, c2i, pos, rels, options), paramsfp)

            #print 'Initializing joint model'
            parser = learner.jPosDepLearner(words, pos, rels, w2i, c2i, options)
        

        for epoch in xrange(options.epochs):
            print '\n-----------------\nStarting epoch', epoch + 1

            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                if epoch == 0:
                    parser.trainer.restart(learning_rate=0.001) 
                elif epoch == 10:
                    parser.trainer.restart(learning_rate=0.0005)
                else:
                    parser.trainer.restart(learning_rate=0.00025)

            parser.Train(options.conll_train)
            
            if options.conll_dev == "N/A":  
                parser.Save(os.path.join(options.output, os.path.basename(options.model)))
                
            else: 
                devPredSents = parser.Predict(options.conll_dev)
                
                count = 0
                lasCount = 0
                uasCount = 0
                posCount = 0
                poslasCount = 0
                for idSent, devSent in enumerate(devPredSents):
                    conll_devSent = [entry for entry in devSent if isinstance(entry, utils.ConllEntry)]
                    
                    for entry in conll_devSent:
                        if entry.id <= 0:
                            continue
                        if entry.pos == entry.pred_pos and entry.parent_id == entry.pred_parent_id and entry.pred_relation == entry.relation:
                            poslasCount += 1
                        if entry.pos == entry.pred_pos:
                            posCount += 1
                        if entry.parent_id == entry.pred_parent_id and entry.pred_relation == entry.relation:
                            lasCount += 1
                        if entry.parent_id == entry.pred_parent_id:
                            uasCount += 1
                        count += 1
                        
                print "---\nLAS accuracy:\t%.2f" % (float(lasCount) * 100 / count)
                print "UAS accuracy:\t%.2f" % (float(uasCount) * 100 / count)
                print "POS accuracy:\t%.2f" % (float(posCount) * 100 / count)
                print "POS&LAS:\t%.2f" % (float(poslasCount) * 100 / count)
                
                score = float(poslasCount) * 100 / count
                if score >= highestScore:
                    parser.Save(os.path.join(options.output, os.path.basename(options.model)))
                    highestScore = score
                    eId = epoch + 1
                
                print "Highest POS&LAS: %.2f at epoch %d" % (highestScore, eId)
```

Now, I have tried to write a separate script for the optimization, but I really have no idea how it can read CoNLL-U files! Here's my tentative (non-working) code (where jPTDP is the name of the model):

```
import pickle, utils, learner, os, os.path, time, jPTDP
import optuna

df = open("Desktop/experimentoptuna/train.conllu")
def objective(trial):
    lstmlayers = trial.suggest_int("lstmlayers", 1, 2)
    lstmdims = trial.suggest_int("lstmdims", 128, 256)
    hidden = trial.suggest_int("hidden", 100, 200, 300)
    epochs = trial.suggest_int("epochs", 25, 30, 35)

    model = jPTDP(
        lstmlayers=lstmlayers,
        lstmdims=lstmdims,
        hidden=hidden,
        epochs=epochs
    )
    study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=15)
```

Any help much appreciated!